# Image upload in Django no error

Tags: django, python-2.7

Trying to save images to a specific folder in django. I get no error but the file doesn't show up where its supposed to.

Here is the model:

```
class FileUploadHandler(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to='/wiki/static/')
```

View:

```
def image_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            FileUploadHandler(request.FILES['image'])
            form.save
            return render_to_response('wiki/gallery.html')
    else:
        form = UploadImageForm()
    return render_to_response('wiki/gallery.html', RequestContext(request, {'form': form}))
```

Totally stumped since I don't get an error.

Comment: What do you have in your ``settings.py`` under ``MEDIA_ROOT`` and ``MEDIA_URL``? Where is your folder ``wiki`` placed?

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT = '/Python27/Lib/site-packages/django/bin/mideastinfo/wiki/static/'

Comment: Could it have to do with permissions?

Comment: That could be eventually an issue. Why don't you upload the within your project?

Comment: The project is on system python. I didn't use a virtual env. I know better now, but to finish this up, I'm just going to keep it on system install

Answer (score 2):

don't you need parenthesis at the end of `form.save`,
i.e. `form.save()`

Comment: Yes, that was an oversight, thank you. However, that didn't seem to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileUploadHandler.objects.create(file=request.FILES['image'])
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.create
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files